# Sphinx cannot be found on your system (OSX)

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, ruby-on-rails, osx-snow-leopard, sphinxsearch

I recently installed sphinx, mysql etc. and everything works fine as well. However, I always get the message:

> Sphinx cannot be found on your system. You may need to configure the following
>   settings in your config/sphinx.yml file:
>
> - bin_path
> - searchd_binary_name
> - indexer_binary_name
>
> For more information, read the documentation:

I configured the bin_path in sphinx.yml to

```
development:
  bin_path: '/usr/local/bin'
  searchd_binary_name: 'searchd'
  indexer_binary_name: 'indexer'
```

With no success. How can I get rid of that message?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the bin_path ought to do the trick.  You shouldn't need to specify the commands.

If you installed with mac ports, sphinx may be in /opt/local/bin

Try a 'locate searchd' from the command line to make sure you are looking in the right place.

Comment: I uninstalled the version built from sources and installed it out of the mac ports tree, now it works. Thanks.